# MS SQL equivalent of MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to port an old project from Linux onto current Windows (mostly as a learning exercise). The database side is all MySQL and every table uses `TYPE=MyISAM`, which I've done a little reading on but can't find any MS SQL equivalent. Is there one, or is it unnecessary? Any info would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM is a non-transactional database system. That means it has no rollback features in case database updates fail to commit. This makes it fault intolerant. On top of that its tables don't support foreign key relationships.

MS-SQL was built from the ground up to be a fully relational database system with transactional data handling for commit/rollback.

MySQL basically had to be updated to support what MS-SQL already is by adding the InnoDB database engine. There is no MyISAM equivalent in MS-SQL because it is older technology that Microsoft wished to exceed.

Comment: Interesting. So this project is a game server, my assumption based on what you say is that they don't care about rollback because the data is coming in so frequently and it's not a catastrophe if connection is lost. Maybe there's a speed benefit there? I'm just making assumptions